# Issue Sending In-App Messages to Production Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to send in-app messages to my Android users. During the creation of an in-app campaign, I encounter the following warning. While I'm able to view Crashlytics logs from my production users, I'm unable to send them in-app messages. It seems that it takes only my debug sessions into consideration.

[image]

- I have enabled Firebase In-app messaging from Google Cloud. I can send in-app messages to debug apps.
- I've added both release and debug SHA-1 keys to the Project settings.

But I'm still unable to send in-app messages to my production users.

Any insights, suggestions, or solutions you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!